# Pivot some rows to new columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm after a pythonic and *pandemic* (from *pandas*, pun not intended =) way to pivot some rows in a dataframe into new columns.

My data has this format:

```
           dof  foo  bar  qux
idxA idxB                    
100  101     1   10   30   50
     101     2   11   31   51
     101     3   12   32   52
     102     1   13   33   53
     102     2   14   34   54
     102     3   15   35   55
200  101     1   16   36   56
     101     2   17   37   57
     101     3   18   38   58
     102     1   19   39   59
     102     2   20   40   60
     102     3   21   41   61
```

The variables `foo`, `bar` and `qux` actually have 3 dimensional coordinates, which I would like to call `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, `bar1`, ..., `qux3`. These are identified by the column `dof`. Each row represents one axis in 3D, `dof == 1` is the x axis, `dof == 2` the y axis and `dof == 3` is the z axis.

So, here is the final dataframe I want:

```
           foo1  bar1  qux1  foo2  bar2  qux2  foo3  bar3  qux3
idxA idxB                                                      
100  101     10    30    50    11    31    51    12    32    52
     102     13    33    53    14    34    54    15    35    55
200  101     16    36    56    17    37    57    18    38    58
     102     19    39    59    20    40    60    21    41    61
```

---

Here is what I have done.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[100, 101, 1, 10, 30, 50],
        [100, 101, 2, 11, 31, 51],
        [100, 101, 3, 12, 32, 52],
        [100, 102, 1, 13, 33, 53],
        [100, 102, 2, 14, 34, 54],
        [100, 102, 3, 15, 35, 55],
        [200, 101, 1, 16, 36, 56],
        [200, 101, 2, 17, 37, 57],
        [200, 101, 3, 18, 38, 58],
        [200, 102, 1, 19, 39, 59],
        [200, 102, 2, 20, 40, 60],
        [200, 102, 3, 21, 41, 61],
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['idxA', 'idxB', 'dof', 'foo', 'bar', 'qux'])
df.set_index(['idxA', 'idxB'], inplace=True)


#
# Here is where the magic happens - and I'm not too happy about this implementation
# 

# Create an ampty dataframe with the same indexes
df2 = df[df.dof == 1].reset_index()[['idxA', 'idxB']]
df2.set_index(['idxA', 'idxB'], inplace=True)

# Loop through each DOF and add columns for `bar`, `foo` and `qux` manually.
for pivot in [1, 2, 3]:
    df2.loc[:, 'foo%d' % pivot] = df[df.dof == pivot]['foo']
    df2.loc[:, 'bar%d' % pivot] = df[df.dof == pivot]['bar']
    df2.loc[:, 'qux%d' % pivot] = df[df.dof == pivot]['qux']
```

However I'm not too happy with these `.loc` calls and incremental column additions inside a loop. I thought that `pandas` being awesome as it is would have a neater way of doing that.

Comment: I'm too lazy to try an implementation, but perhaps you should look into a multi-index where the innermost index has size 3.

Answer (score 1):

## `groupby`

When iterating over the values in a column, it is bad practice to hardcode the values (`for pivot in [1, 2, 3]`). A better way would have been `for pivot in df["dof"].unique()`, but the best way is with [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)

To see what happens in the `groupby`, I try it first with an iteration, and printing the groups

```
for pivot, data in df.groupby("dof"):
    print(pivot)
    print(data)
```

Then I get to work with one of the `data` to mold it the way I want. In this case, we don't need the column `dof` any more, since we have it in the `pivot` variable, and we rename the columns using `rename`

```
for pivot, data in df.groupby("dof"):
    print(pivot)
    print(
        data.drop(columns="dof").rename(
            mapper={
                column_name: f"{column_name}{pivot}"
                for column_name in data.columns
            },
            axis=1,
        )
    )
```

Then we can use `pd.concat` to stitch it together

```
pd.concat(
    [
        data.drop(columns="dof").rename(
            mapper={
                column_name: f"{column_name}{pivot}"
                for column_name in data.columns
            },
            axis=1,
        )
        for pivot, data in df.groupby("dof")
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

## unstack

An alternative is with `unstack`:

From you description, `dof` is part of the index, so add it there. Then you can use `DataFrame.unstack` to bring it to the columns.

> ```
> df2 = df.set_index("dof", append=True).unstack("dof")
> ```

```
        foo foo foo bar bar bar qux qux qux
dof     1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
idxA idxB                                   
100 101 10  11  12  30  31  32  50  51  52
100 102 13  14  15  33  34  35  53  54  55
200 101 16  17  18  36  37  38  56  57  58
200 102 19  20  21  39  40  41  59  60  61
```

If you are okay with a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), which will be handier then the concatenated strings in most cases, you can leave it at that. If you want it in the form you have it, you can do `df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f"{x[0]}{x[1]}")`.